# Load Style Inside PHP and HTML code using PHP variable

Tags: php, html

I want hide my one button and so I am looking  for add style  = "display:none;" in it but since I am already using PHP code for echo that button, I am confused how I can use it. I am trying to do it like below

```
 <?php
 $style = "";

 if($this->session->userdata('user_id') == $member['user_id']) {                         
     $style = "style='display:none;'";                   
 }

 if ($member2 == 0){                               
     echo '<a href="'.site_url('members/addfriend/'.$member['user_id']).'" class="btn btn-primary">Add As Friend <?php echo $style;?> </a>';
 } else {
     echo '<a href="'.site_url('members/removefriend/'.$member['user_id']).'" class="btn btn-primary">Remove Friend </a>';
 }
 ?>
```

I am looking for apply above style code in my Add Friend button but I am not getting idea how I can use $style variable in my below line code

```
echo '<a href="'.site_url('members/addfriend/'.$member['user_id']).'" class="btn btn-primary">Add As Friend <?php echo $style;?> </a>';
```

Let me know if someone can help me for do it.
Thanks!

Comment: For one, you created a parse error having PHP interpreter tags and an echo inside an existing echo and already being *in* PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's probably just a syntax error. Try it like this:

```
<?php

$style = "";
if ($this->session->userdata('user_id') == $member['user_id']) {
    $style = "style='display:none;'";
}

if ($member2 == 0) {
    echo '<a href="'.site_url('members/addfriend/'.$member['user_id']);.'" class="btn btn-primary">Add As Friend "'.$style.'"> </a>'; 
   //Here's the change!
} else {
    echo '<a href="' . site_url('members/removefriend/' . $member['user_id']) . '" class="btn btn-primary">Remove Friend </a>';
}


?>
```

You had a php opening tag inside php, that won't ever work.